# How to suppress request logging in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I've searched for how to do this, and have come up empty handed.

The nginx web server has proper request logging and so I do not need Laravel to log these at all. They add little information and for health checks in particular, are spammy:

```
- -  08/Sep/2022:03:35:24 +0000 "GET /index.php" 404
```

Does anyone know how they can be suppressed without forcibly editing `vendor` code?

Comment: Laravel does not log each request. That looks like the PHP-FPM log. I don't recommend disabling that, but changing the format to something more useful might be good

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of that! nginx already does well formatted request logging so I can probably just disable request logging in php-fpm.

Comment: I am using the format noted in [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/272626/66807) mainly for the memory and CPU details which nginx is not able to share, in case that's useful to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From @apokryfos in comments.

`Laravel` does not log each request. That looks like the `PHP-FPM` log. I don't recommend disabling that, but changing the format to something more useful might be good. I am using the format noted in [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/272626/66807) mainly for the memory and CPU details which `nginx` is not able to share, in case that's useful to you.